# Android Studio - Что за красный прямоугольник?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-resources

Выводится такой красный прямоугольник  когда вывожу строки в Resources. strings.xml c с комбинацией ALT+ENTER , как только появляется этот прямоугольник комбинация ALT+ENTER не работает! Приходится закрывать окно и заново открывать после чего комбинация работает , до следушего появления прямоугольника, что обычно происходит после перврго или второго вывода строки в strings.xml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот прямоугольник означает рефакроринг выделенной области. Нажмите еще раз `Enter`, чтобы он исчез

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае данных прямоугольник появляться после дублирования строки.
Создается новая строка кода и текст который выделен красным можно редактировать.
Если нажать Enter то текст перестает подсвечивать.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понял как воссоздать данную проблему у себя, но:

`Alt + Enter` используется для вывода всяких подсказок(в случае синтаксических и подобных ошибок) и выполнения дополнительных действий.

А в данном случае, я так понимаю, необходимо использовать автокомплит - комбинацию `Ctrl + Space` - тогда буду предоставлены возможные варианты.

А красный прямоугольник обычно вроде показывал какой из параметров или аргументов необходимо заполнить в данным момент.. по крайней мере так для методов было.